# Debian: LSB package for OpenPrinting driver

Tags: debian, package-management, cups, printer, lsb

I have an [old printer](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&locale=en&productCode=1100_COLOR_JETPRINTER&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_UK#1) which requires the LSB package in order to install the OpenPrinting driver in Debian:
[Preparation of LSB-compliant distributions](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/driverpackages)

However, the current version of Debian no longer support LSB:
[Debian discontinued LSB support in 2015](https://wiki.debian.org/LSB)

Therefore, I'm not able to install the OpenPrinting driver of this printer on Debian Buster.

Any idea how to solve that?

---

## Follow-up

Following some advices, I tried to install the LSB package from Ubuntu.

So, I downloaded the LSB package from Ubuntu 19.04 available at https://pkgs.org/
Then I tried to install via the following command:

```
dpkg -i lsb_10.2019031300ubuntu1_all.deb
```

However, some dependencies were missing:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb:
lsb depends on lsb-core (>= 10.2019031300ubuntu1); however: Package lsb-core is not installed.
lsb depends on lsb-printing (>= 10.2019031300ubuntu1); however: Package lsb-printing is not installed.
```

Then I've downloaded the lsb-core package and tried to install it:

```
dpkg -i lsb-core_10.2019031300ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Again, dependencies issues:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-core:
lsb-core depends on libncurses5; however: Package libncurses5 is not installed.
lsb-core depends on lsb-invalid-mta (>= 10.2019031300ubuntu1) however: Package lsb-invalid-mta is not installed.
lsb-core depends on at; however: Package at is not installed.
lsb-core depends on binutils; however: Package binutils is not installed.
lsb-core depends on ed; however: Package ed is not installed.
lsb-core depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:Package libc6-dev is not installed. Package libc-dev is not installed.
lsb-core depends on cups-bsd | lpr; however: Package cups-bsd is not installed. Package lpr is not installed.
lsb-core depends on m4; however: Package m4 is not installed.
lsb-core depends on mailx | mailutils; however: Package mailx is not installed. Package mailutils is not installed.
lsb-core depends on make; however: Package make is not installed.
lsb-core depends on patch; however: Package patch is not installed.
lsb-core depends on pax; however: Package pax is not installed.
lsb-core depends on rsync; however: Package rsync is not installed.
lsb-core depends on alien (>= 8.36); however: Package alien is not installed.
lsb-core depends on lsb-security (>= 10.2019031300ubuntu1); however: Package lsb-security is not installed.
lsb-core depends on time; however: Package time is not installed.
```

It seems that this is not the way to go.
Any idea?

Comment: I can see you having (3) choices: 1) switch to a distro that still has LSB support (Mint comes to mind); 2) try to build Debian packages from the sources; 3) buy a new printer.

Comment: @ajgringo619 > _"2) try to build Debian packages from the sources;"_ Mind to explain how to do that?

Comment: I tried to make sense of all the source RPMs and didn't have much success. I've built RPMs from source, but haven't tried to convert them to DEBs. I'm wondering if you could download the DEBs from another Ubuntu distro, or maybe get the source DEBs from said distro and build a Debian package. I'm just speculating at this point; I've never tried any of what I'm suggesting. Check on https://pkgs.org/download/lsb - this will at least give you an idea of what packages for what distros are available.

Comment: @ajgringo619 > _"I'm wondering if you could download the DEBs from another Ubuntu distro"_ Any guess which Ubuntu version is closest to Debian Buster? v19.10? v19.0?

Comment: @ajgringo619 > _"maybe get the source DEBs from said distro and build a Debian package."_ Not sure if I understand correctly. You mean download the DEB package and manually install? Like `dpkg -i lsb.deb`?

Comment: I would try 19.04. Yes, download the lsb deb and manually install it. It should complain if there are any dependencies missing, either download them or find them in the normal package repos. I would suggest making a backup, in case something doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101383/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-mark-messa).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lsb support on Debian is still provided through metapackages, just as they are on Ubuntu. So you might have all the packages you need available from `apt`. Run `apt-cache search "Linux Standard Base"` to show which packages are available. Debian Jessie (oldstable) should have all the packages you need.

If there are certain packages missing from your distribution. You can avoid dependency issues by downloading the oldstable Debian version(s) instead of the Ubuntu equivalent(s).

You can find the [oldstable lsb packages here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lsb).

Then create a directory, `~/lsb_packages` for example, and download all the packages to this directory. This way, you can install the packages using a single command:

```
sudo apt install ~/lsb_packages/*.deb
```

I would also recommend using `sudo apt install` instead of `sudo dpkg -i` to install the driver download as `apt` will automatically take care of any native dependency issues.

Remember, you will have to keep track of security updates.